# RichFaces table pagination read data with robot

Tags: java, jsf, seam, jsf-1.2

I need to conect at a website, and read the data table, the website is created with Seam and the pagination is something strange, with a component called slider.

My problem is, I need to read all the data, the first page I'm able to read with `HttpClient` using `HttpPost` correct, but when I pass to the seconde page, it won't return any value, returns the layout but with no data on it.

The question is, is possible to create a robot to read the datatable and the pagination above in Seam with JSF 1.2?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Looks like your managed beans are request scoped thus the data doesn't persist in navigation.

Comment: ok, and is there any option to read the remaining pages? I need a robot, because the data is too long...

Comment: It would be better if you show some code to show your current design so we could guide you on that basis.

Comment: I don´t have access to the code where the table with the data is, but I notice that the pagination is made like this: new Richfaces.Slider("j_id673:j_id674",{'showArrows':true,'sliderValue':'0','width':'250px','minValue':'1','onchange':'A4J.AJAX.Submit(\'j_id673\',event,{\'status\':\'_viewRoot:status\',\'similarityGroupingId\':\'j_id673:j_id675\',\'parameters\':{\'j_id673:j_id675\':\'j_id673:j_id675\'} ,\'eventsQueue\':\'\',\'containerId\':\'j_id614\',\'actionUrl\':\'/primeirograu/Painel/painel_usuario/advogado.seam\'} )','maxValue':'2'} )

Comment: @RodrigoFerrari do you mean you want to screen-scrape an AJAX rendered page?

Comment: @kolossus correct, I want to do it, the main page it´s ok, but the second request when I need to send a request for the second page it won´t print the screen. Is there any issue known about capture a page loaded with ajax that uses the SEAM Framework to render it?